# Complete log Display in net suite with suite script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have the json object(itemDetailsObj) with more than 10000 fields,those i want to print in

```
var itemDetailsObj=JSON.stringify(currentRecord);
```

`log.debug({
               title: 'Quantity of Item ',
               details: itemDetailsObj
           });`

but i'm getting few fields only. 
How can i print all the fields using any way in suite script 2.0.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

When using `log.debug`, you do not need to call JSON.stringify on the object, as NetSuite will do that automatically for you.

```
log.debug({title: 'Quantity of Item', details: currentRecord});
```

Note that NetSuite truncates any resulting string over 3999 characters, so you may not see the complete object.

As a note, [this is a great](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-html-script-note/lipldhgjkmfhamocfcdijcdgjcikcbkk) Chrome extension for viewing objects in the log. It pretty prints the object.

Answer (score 1):

[NetSuite](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4430385329.html) truncates characters with string over 3999 characters. So you cannot log a complete record object. You can do the following

1. print only the required fields.
2. create a custom record for logs and then create logs in your custom record.
3. Create a local file in NetSuite file cabinet and email the file using NetSuite's *email* module.

Although creating a custom record creates an overhead if you only want this once for debugging purpose.